# Exporting directory file names

Tags: powershell, export, get-childitem

I'm trying to create a script which prompts for a path which is to be exported onto a .csv which displays the names of the folders and the named of the contents of the folders. Something like this, but without the Mode & Length.

I would like to keep the gaps between each folder.

Example - (Without the Mode/Length)

```
Directory: C:\Users\khalifam\Desktop\TestFolder1


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       24/07/2019     15:50                TestFolder2
d-----       24/07/2019     15:50                TestFolder3


    Directory: C:\Users\khalifam\Desktop\TestFolder1\TestFolder2


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       30/05/2019     11:05           1696 EC2Key1.pem


    Directory: C:\Users\khalifam\Desktop\TestFolder1\TestFolder3


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       31/05/2019     16:16          22027 Dropbox-f
```

My script so far:

```
$FilePathLocation = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the the path of the fold you wish to export'

Set-Location $FilePathLocation

gci -Recurse | select DirectoryName, FullName | FT
```

Current output:

```
Please enter the the path of the fold you wish to export: C:\Users\khalifam\Desktop\TestFolder1

DirectoryName                                     FullName                                                                            Root
-------------                                     --------                                                                            ----
                                                  C:\Users\khalifam\Desktop\TestFolder1\TestFolder2                                   C:\
                                                  C:\Users\khalifam\Desktop\TestFolder1\TestFolder3                                   C:\
C:\Users\khalifam\Desktop\TestFolder1\TestFolder2 C:\Users\khalifam\Desktop\TestFolder1\TestFolder2\EC2Key1.pem
C:\Users\khalifam\Desktop\TestFolder1\TestFolder3 C:\Users\khalifam\Desktop\TestFolder1\TestFolder3\Dropbox-CCEN-Course.docx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enumerate directories recursively first, then process the content of each directory without recursion. Note that the output generated by this is **NOT** an actual CSV.

```
Get-ChildItem $FilePathLocation -Directory -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    "{0}`n" -f $_.FullName
    Get-ChildItem $_.FullName |
        Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime |
        Format-Table |
        Out-String
} | Set-Content 'output.txt'
```

Also note that this requires PowerShell v3 or newer. If you're stuck with an older version you need to remove the parameter `-Directory` and use a `Where-Object` filter instead.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks, would you be able to explain the logic behind this please?

Answer (score 0):

You have most of it.

```
$FilePathLocation = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the the path of the fold you wish to export'

Get-ChildItem $FilePathLocation -Recurse | select DirectoryName, FullName | Export-Csv C:\PathStuff.csv
```

You can't use Format-Table if you want to export to a csv, it messes up the output